# inline assembly instruction with two return registers

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I have an custom instruction for a processor, it has two return registers and two operands like:

```
MINMAX rdMin, RdMax, rs1, rs2
```

It returns the minimum and maximum out of rs1 and rs2. I have verified this instruction using assembly program. It works fine. Now I want to use this instruction from GCC using inline assembly. I tried the following code, but it did not give the correct values of rdMin and rdMax. Is there any mistake in the syntax.

```
int main() {
   unsigned int array[10] = { 45, 75,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  int op1=16,op2=18,out,out1,out2;
   //asm for AVG rd, rs1, rs2
  __asm__ volatile (
                "avg %[my_out], %[my_op1], %[my_op2]\n"
                : [my_out] "=&r" (out)
                : [my_op1] "r" (op1),[my_op2] "r" (op2)
        );
   //asm for MinMax rdMin, rdMax, rs1, rs2
  __asm__ volatile (
                "minmax %[my_out1], %[my_out2], %[my_op1], %[my_op2]\n"
                : [my_out1] "=r" (out1), [my_out2] "=r" (out2)
                : [my_op1] "r" (op1), [my_op2] "r" (op2)
        );

  array[3] = out;
  array[4] = out1;
  array[5] = out2;
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks okay. Verify the generated assembly code either using `gcc -S` or disassembly.

Comment: You don't need `volatile` if your asm blocks act like pure functions with no side-effects, so the same input will give the same output.  (And if the output(s) aren't needed, the compiler is free to optimize it away.)  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.  Also, unless `avg` has a problem with its output being the same register as one of its inputs, you don't need an early-clobber output.  It's fine to let the compiler emit `avg r1, r1, r2` or something.

Comment: Also, `[name] "=r" (name)` is fine.  asm operand `[name]`s are a different namespace from C variable names, so you could make it more readable by leaving out the `my_` everywhere.  Or better, call your operands `[min]`, `[max]`, `[in1]` and `[in2]`.

Comment: If there's an intrinsic for either of those instructions, that's usually better than inline-asm.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm.  See also other links in the [inline-assembly tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info).

Comment: @Jester, yes with -S, generated the assembly code and then simulated using both instruction set processor and also with ModelSim. I have the RTL as well, of the processor to run the code.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem then? If you checked the assembly and that is fine, then the problem must be with your instruction.

Comment: Sorry, @Jester, may be i could not explain it properly. We have a ASIP, for which i can add different instructions. And then write assembly code for that ASIP to check the functionality. This assembly can be simulated using instruction set simulator like dlxsim or hardware simulator like Modelsim. Alternatively, one can write C code directly for this ASIP having new instructions. If i simulate the assembly test code, it works fine. but I run the C test code, it did not show the intended output. I just want to confirm whether I am writing this MINMAX instruction correctly using inline asm????

Comment: Yes, the inline asm seems fine **but you check that by examining the output of gcc -S or a disassembler**. That's how you verify that the inlining happened properly. If that assembly is fine, your problem must be elsewhere. Also note that the posted code has no observable output whatsoever, in fact with optimization enabled the array can be removed.

Comment: OK @Jester, I will recheck it.

Comment: "you check that by examining the output of gcc -S or a disassembler" - This is only kinda true.  Yes, the code it generates right now might be right.  But (seemingly) unrelated to surrounding code, minor changes in the optimization settings, newer versions of the compiler, etc can all result in different assembly being output. You'd need to check this output repeatedly.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd but it isn't right right now either :) As in, he is not getting a correct result.

Comment: Yes. Dear @Jester it worked while using "=&r" with output registers.

Comment: Means your instruction does not work with same input and output operands.

Comment: Yes you are right